Using glossaries package with a custom alphabetical order
Is it possible to define a custom alphabetical order for the Glossaries package? I want to set up a lexicon for my constructed language, which has a slightly different alphabetical order than the English language. (Basically a couple more diacritics and characters.)

Welcome! You want to ask this question about the underlying indexing method you're using e.g. makeindex or xindy or whatever, because makeglossaries is just a wrapper. Alternatively, you might want to ask it about bib2gls if you're doing it that way. Can you provide code for a minimal example we can compile to test? And can you tell us what the ordering is?

I'm still learning LaTeX so I don't yet have code, but the order is as follows: ABCDÐEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ.

We need a minimal example document to show us how you are using glossaries. Otherwise any answer may or may not apply to your setup. You just want a minimal document from \documentclass{} to \end{document} which loads glossaries with your configuration, defines a couple of index entries which would get mis-ordered, uses and prints those entries. You don't need to show any attempt to change the ordering. Just provide code to setup the problem.
